# Generating a form dynamically in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I have my form information in a JSON object(Custom Format). Now i have to populate the From and display in predefined placeholder. I came across this post http://neyeon.com/2011/01/creating-forms-with-json-and-jquery/, which is very helpful.

But the problem is, i have to parse my JSON and then i have to create the new JSON in the required format so that the form will be created. Is this the right way to do it? or is there any other options available for me to do this?

Comment: The other option I can think of would be changing the plugin to accept the format of your JSON, but I think parsing, changing, and unparsing the JSON would be easier.

Comment: how does the json obj look like please post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the author's code expects a certain structure for it's API and it differs from what you're creating, then yes, you'll have to translate. There's no "JSON Form" standard here to really dictate whether you should format your data a certain way.

If there's a well known, popular, jQuery form plugin (I've never heard of this one), it might make sense for you to simply format your data accordingly from the get go. OTOH, you might have better ideas and specialized needs anyway so that might not make sense either.

Either way, it shouldn't be too much work. Just write up a neat conversion function so that you can do your translation consistently.

Comment: As per your suggestion, We have implemented our own logic using Factory pattern. It working pretty well.